# How to batch-rename files by date?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, rename, batch-processing

What commands could I use to rename a few hundred files that are currently named

```
file.2003-01-02.txt
file.2003-01-04.txt
```

... and so on? I would like them to be named:

```
file_y2003m01d02.txt
file_y2003m01d04.txt
```

... etc.

In other words, `file.2007-12-09.txt` would become `file_y2007m12d09`. Is there a simple set of commands to do this?

Similarly I have another problem, where files are named `file_y2003m02d01_grid.txt`. I would like to know how to remove `_grid` from each filename, so that it matches the format I proposed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rename` command:

```
rename 's/^file\.([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})\.txt$/file_y$1m$2d$3.txt/' *
```

This uses [Perl regular expression substitution](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/sandtr.html) to transform filenames. The command above says:

1. Find files starting `^` with `file.` (the `.` has to be escaped, otherwise it matches any character), followed by the captured `()` group `[0-9]{4}` (a digit, 4 times), then `-`, then another captured group of a digit twice, etc., and ending `$` with `.txt`;
2. Then, rename those files to `file_y` followed by the first captured group `$1`, followed by `m`, followed by the second captured group `$2`, etc., and ending with `.txt`.

You should also be able to work out how to use the same command to solve your second problem, with what you no know about how `rename` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sed:

for example:

```
ls | while read f; do echo "mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/\./_y/;s/-/m/;s/-/d/')"; done
```

This will show you the commands that bash will run.  To actually do the move, remove the echo and quotes:

```
ls | while read f; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/\./_y/;s/-/m/;s/-/d/'); done
```